# How to utilize dojo uploading files via AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, upload, dojo

I would like to use the `dojox.form.Uploader` widget to handle file uploads to the server via AJAX.

I included the needed definitions:

```
dojo.require('dojox.form.Uploader');
dojo.require('dojox.form.uploader.plugins.HTML5');
```

I declaratively created an instance of `Uploader`:

```
<div name="docUpload" multiple="false" type="file" dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" id="docUpload" label="Upload Doc" uploadOnSelect="true" url="/ajax.php?foo=bar">
    <script type="dojo/connect" event="onComplete">
        /* ... */
    </script>
</div>
```

The `uploadOnSelect` seems to work somehow, because `/ajax.php` gets a request, which is visible in the messagelog. Furthermore the js console receives a `COMPLETED` message after a few seconds.

Strangely the `$_FILES` array in `/ajax.php` remains empty. I'm logging the following:

```
syslog(LOG_WARNING, json_encode($_REQUEST));
syslog(LOG_WARNING, json_encode($_FILES));
```

Output:

***Dec  6 13:27:09 reline httpd2-prefork: {"foo":"bar"}
Dec  6 13:27:09 reline httpd2-prefork: []***

Is my understanding of how to PHP-process the uploaded file wrong? Or is it a technical problem?

**EDIT**

I tried wrapping the widget inside a multipart-form but id didn't have any effect:

```
<form method="post" action="/ajax.php?foo=bar" id="docUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div name="docUpload" multiple="false" type="file" dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" id="docUpload" label="Upload Doc" uploadOnSelect="true">
        <script type="dojo/connect" event="onComplete">
            /* ... */
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Log output is the same:

***Dec  6 16:04:20 reline httpd2-prefork: {"foo":"bar"}
Dec  6 16:04:20 reline httpd2-prefork: []***

Comment: Is your uploader inside a multipart form ?

Comment: No it wasn't - I tried your approach and wrapped it inside a form, but it didn't have any effect... :( (-> see my edit)

Comment: I decided to use the deprecated `dojox.form.FileUploader`, which strangely works very well in contrast to `dojox.form.Uploader`...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't entirely answering your question, but I had the same problems with the dojo fileuploader a couple of months ago, and decided to use this - http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ - it is very feature-rich and does the job perfectly well.  Easy to integrate.

Cheers,
Ed

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! I decided to use the deprecated `dojox.form.FileUploader`, which strangely works very well in contrast to `dojox.form.Uploader`...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<script type="dojo/connect" event="onComplete">
    /* ... */
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="dojo/connect" data-dojo-event="onComplete">
    /* ... */
</script>
```